# Как через Javascript вытащить файл по его типу(mpeg) из сайта?

Tags: javascript, dom, сниффер

Суть:
Есть https сайт с медиа(музыка, видео, картинки). В инструментах разработчика на вкладке "Сеть" все эти медиа замечательно видно по графе "Тип": [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Тип mpeg,lpeg,png и т.д. Кликнув по ним, через ПКМ можно получить прямую ссылку на файл.

**Вопрос:** как средствами js вытащить эти обьекты из сайта?
P.s: простите за мой французский, затрудняюсь точнее сформулировать вопрос.

Comment: А сайт ваш или чужой?

Answer (score 0):

`function downloadURI(uri, name) 
{
    var link = document.createElement("a");
    link.download = name;
    link.href = uri;
    link.click();
}`

Попробуй использовать этот метод. Uri - ссылка по которой открывается файл, name - имя файла при скачивании.